# Wiring Pi - BCM 20 works with a button, but not BCM 21 :-(

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

I have two switches (buttons). Red is connected to physical pin 38 (BCM 20) and green to physical pin 40 (BCM 21). I call `wiringPiSetupGPIO()` it returns 0. When I use

```c
pullUpDnControl(redSwitch, PUD_UP);   // redSwitch = 20
pullUpDnControl(greenSwitch,PUD_UP); // greenSwitch = 21;
```

and then print

```
digitalRead(redSwitch), digitalRead(greenSwitch)
```

red switch is always 0. The greenSwitch prints, 0 when it is pressed, 1 otherwise.

I could have *sworn* I had this working on a Raspberry Pi at home. It *might* be a problem with the ribbon, but does anyone have another idea as to why this might be misbehaving?

As per a request, the code is below. I am running jumpers directly out of a ribbon and then closing them for testing purposes, but my output is always:

red: 0, green: 1

unless I connect pin 21 to ground, when I get:

red: 0, green: 0

red should be high (1) to start, but it is not.

Note that if I switch to pin 7, redSwitch works as advertised ... what's so special about pin 20?

```
const int redLED = 14;
const int yellowLED = 15;
const int greenLED = 18;
const int blueLED = 24; // 23 didn't work

const int redSwitch = 20; // this doesn't work
const int greenSwitch = 21; // this does

const int dht22 = 16;
const int buzzer = 25;

const int loopDelay = 125; // to avoid reporting multiple switch pushes
const int note = 880;

void setup();
void loop();
void switchDetection();
void flashAll();

void setup(){
    int status = wiringPiSetupGpio();
    printf("Status is %d\n",status);

    pullUpDnControl(redSwitch, PUD_UP);
    pullUpDnControl(greenSwitch, PUD_UP);   

    status = softToneCreate(buzzer);    
    printf("Soft tone create status: %d\n",status);

}

void loop(){

    while(1){
        printf("red: %d, green: %d\n",digitalRead(redSwitch),digitalRead(greenSwitch));
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your post with your complete code in a code block and an image of your wiring.

Comment: Are you getting the pin numbers right? https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin40_gpio21

Comment: That might be my problem, but I have const int redSwitch = 20; const int greenSwitch = 21;

Comment: What version of the WiringPi library do you have? You need v2.46 for 3B+ & all earlier Raspberries. V2.46 doesn't work on a 3A+.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your responses, I really appreciate them! I downloaded pigpio and also consulted with the author of WiringPi, and it turns out that I had fried several GPIO pins (no idea how: until yesterday I did not even know that was a possibility), including pin # 20.